# What are 'folders of this type' in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, user-folders

I like my folders in Windows 10 to show in 'Detail' view but Windows 10 is trying to be helpful and changes it according to some rule that I do not understand.

So each time this happens I change the 'View' option to 'Detail' and go to options and do 'Apply this view to all folders of this type'.

My question/s:

1. What are the 'folders of this type'?
2. How do I figure out what type is any particular folder?
3. Can I change the type? or is the type it automatically determined (if so, how is the folder type determined)?

My overall goal it to tell Windows 10 to use the 'Detail' view at all times, 
but I find it interesting to understand what the folder types are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after more digging I think I understand the types of folders that exist in Win 10:

to find what type your folder is

1. right-click on empty space in file explorer and select
   'Properties'
2. go to 'customize' tab

under 'optimize folder for:' there are 5 options:

```
- general items
- documents
- pictures
- music and 
- video
```

now, the question was to make sure that all folder types show 'details' view. 
you have to go through the "Apply this view to all folders of this type" for every one of the 5 types.

Answer (score 1):

"Apply this view to all folders of this type" makes all folders that adhere to a specific template show their files in a specific manner (List, Icons, etc) .

For example, the **Pictures** folder and **Music** folder are optmized to store pictures and music specifically.

In order to show files in all folders in the same manner,

- Select the folder that has the display type that you want(Details view).
- Go to **View Tab > Options > Change folder and search options**.
- Go to the View tab, and click **Apply to folders.**
- That should set the default viewing method as "Details".

Comment: That sounds more like Windows 7. 10 is different - doesn't have Tools & doesn't have a simple 'Apply to All'.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I almost forgot! @Tetsujin Thanks for informing. I have edited the answer to windows 10 steps.

Comment: TY for the edit. hmm... interesting - I was also worried about the wording 'folders of this type'... I just checked it on 7 & 10 & they both say the same thing.

Comment: this is what I did but when you put pictures into a folder Win 10 will recognize it and change how the folder is viewed. now it is defined as 'Picture folder' - whatever that means. my original q was: what are the different types of folders and how to find/change it.

Comment: Yeah - I hate how Windows makes up its own mind... & usually defaults to huge dinner plate icons, when I just want the damn details.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to your user folder, for example if your name is johnblogs, go to C\users\joeblogs
2. make desired view for example, details, size, date
3. right-click on in file explorer and select 'Properties' of that folder
4. go to 'customize' tab
5. select desired view and important is to TICK and select "also apply this template to all subfolders"
6. click ok
7. all subfolders within C\users\joeblogs should have same view